# Getting an entry from a child window?

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics, mainwindow, toplevel

For some reason i can't get the entry from the child window.
I want to get the  entry from the child window and then graph a rectangle.
The error that i get is: x=float(self.txtSide.get())
AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'txtSide'

```
import tkinter as tk
import turtle
tu=turtle


class MainWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Cupe",command=self.Cupe)
        self.button.pack(side="top")

    def Cupe(self):

        c = tk.Toplevel(self)
        c.wm_title("Cupe")

        lab=tk.Label(c,text="Side")
        lab.pack()

        c.txtSide=tk.Entry(c)
        c.txtSide.pack()


        button=tk.Button(c,text="Graph",command=self.graphCupe)
        button.pack(side="bottom")


    def graphCupe(self):
        x=float(self.txtSide.get())
        tu.forward(x)
        tu.left(90)
        tu.forward(x)
        tu.left(90)
        tu.forward(x)
        tu.left(90)
        tu.forward(x)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    main = MainWindow(root)
    main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `self` in `graphCupe` refers to the `MainWindow` instance, and not to the child window. You would need to pass the child window into the `graphCupe` function. This would be one way to do it:

```
    def Cupe(self):
        ...
        button=tk.Button(c,text="Graph",command=lambda: self.graphCupe(c))
        button.pack(side="bottom")

    def graphCupe(self,window):
        x=float(window.txtSide.get())
        ...
```

Now the `graphCupe` function takes the window it needs to operate on, and the button calls the function and passes it its child window.

Comment: The other solution, of course, is to make `txtSide` an attribute of `self` (`self.txtSide=...`)

Comment: That would also work, but if another child window is opened it would overwrite the attribute. Then if child window 1 tries to call `graphCupe()` it'll use the `txtSide` attribute from child window 2.